# Is it possible to fill the second column with something automatically?

Tags: multicol, fill

Is it possible to reach a result like the following without manually repeating `\hrulefill`?

In the actual document, there is no `\hrulefill` but a TikZ grid.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{mwe}
\begin{document}
Some text in one column \blindtext
\begin{multicols}{2}
Some text in two columns \blindtext
\vfill\null
\columnbreak
\hrulefill

\hrulefill

\hrulefill

\hrulefill

\hrulefill

\hrulefill

\hrulefill

\hrulefill

\hrulefill

\hrulefill

\hrulefill

\hrulefill

\hrulefill

\hrulefill
\end{multicols}
\newpage
Some other text in one column \blindtext
\begin{multicols}{2}
Some other text in two columns \blindtext[2]
\vfill\null
\columnbreak
\hrulefill

\hrulefill

\hrulefill

\hrulefill

\hrulefill

\hrulefill

\hrulefill

\hrulefill

\hrulefill

\hrulefill

\hrulefill

\hrulefill

\hrulefill

\hrulefill

\hrulefill

\hrulefill

\hrulefill

\hrulefill

\hrulefill

\hrulefill

\hrulefill

\hrulefill

\hrulefill

\hrulefill

\hrulefill

\hrulefill

\hrulefill

\hrulefill

\hrulefill
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The real question will be, can you accept this answer?

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{mwe}
\begin{document}
Some text in one column \blindtext
\begin{multicols}{2}
Some text in two columns \blindtext
\vfill\null
\columnbreak

\null
\vskip-\baselineskip
\leaders
\hbox to \columnwidth{\hrulefill Pineapple Pizza\hrulefill}
\vfill 
\null


\end{multicols}
\newpage
Some other text in one column \blindtext
\begin{multicols}{2}
Some other text in two columns \blindtext[2]
\vfill\null
\columnbreak

\null
\vskip-\baselineskip
\leaders
\hbox to \columnwidth{\hrulefill Pineapple Pizza\hrulefill}
\vfill 
\null

\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Accepting the answer doesn't mean accepting pineapple pizzas!

Comment: @CarLaTeX oh, but it does.

Comment: No, it does not :D