# Is it possible to fill the second column with a grid automatically?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tcolorbox, multicol

This is a follow-up of [Is it possible to fill the second column with something automatically?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/689309/is-it-possible-to-fill-the-second-column-with-something-automatically)

I would like to (automatically) reach the following result (fill in the second column with a grid):

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable, xparse}

\newtcolorbox[auto counter]{mybox}[2][]{%
    breakable,
    frame hidden,
    opacityback=0,
    sharp corners,
    before skip=10pt,
    enhanced,
    left=6pt,
    right=0pt,
    bottom=0pt,
    boxsep=0pt,
    rightrule=0pt,
    pad at break*=0mm,
    borderline west={1.5pt}{0pt}{red},
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    coltitle=blue,
    title={\thetcbcounter. #2}
    }

\usepackage{mwe}
\begin{document}
Some text in one column \blindtext
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{mybox}{My title}
Some text in two columns \blindtext
\end{mybox}
\vfill\null
\columnbreak
\begin{mybox}{My second title}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[green,thin, step=.5] (0,0) grid (7,7);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{mybox}
\end{multicols}
\newpage
Some other text in one column
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{mybox}{My third title}
Some other text in two columns \blindtext[2]
\end{mybox}
\vfill\null
\columnbreak

\begin{mybox}{My fourth title}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[green,thin, step=.5] (0,0) grid (7,15);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{mybox}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I tried this dirty hack but, of course, it doesn't work:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable, xparse}

\newtcolorbox[auto counter]{mybox}[2][]{%
    breakable,
    frame hidden,
    opacityback=0,
    sharp corners,
    before skip=10pt,
    enhanced,
    left=6pt,
    right=0pt,
    bottom=0pt,
    boxsep=0pt,
    rightrule=0pt,
    pad at break*=0mm,
    borderline west={1.5pt}{0pt}{red},
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    coltitle=blue,
    title={\thetcbcounter. #2}
    }

\newcommand{\squarefill}[2][.5]{\null
    \vskip-\baselineskip
    \leaders
    \hbox to \columnwidth{\hspace{7.5pt}\begin{tikzpicture}   
    \draw[red,line width=1.5pt, overlay](7.27pt,\pgflinewidth) -- (7.27pt,1); \draw[step=#1,green,thin] (.5,\pgflinewidth) grid (#2*#1,#1);
    \end{tikzpicture}}
    \vfill\vskip-\baselineskip
    \null}

\usepackage{mwe}
\begin{document}
Some text in one column \blindtext
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{mybox}{My title}
Some text in two columns \blindtext
\end{mybox}
\vfill\null
\columnbreak
\begin{mybox}{My second title}
\end{mybox}
\squarefill{14}
\end{multicols}
\newpage
Some other text in one column
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{mybox}{My third title}
Some other text in two columns \blindtext[2]
\end{mybox}
\vfill\null
\columnbreak

\begin{mybox}{My fourth title}
\end{mybox}
\squarefill{14}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image]

A solution without `tcolorbox` or TikZ is also acceptable if it gives the desired result.

Comment: I've proposed a solution with `tcolorbox` following your scheme. But if you always want two columns with controlled height, i think it will be easier to use a `tcbraster` construction wich will avoid to specify `equal height group`

Comment: @Ignasi You're right, a `tcbraster` could be the solution, I'll try

Comment: I've added a `tcbitemize` version, hope it helps

Comment: @Ignasi Thank you very much

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a solution with `tcolorbox` and `equal height group` option. All boxes with same `equal height group` label have same height after two compilations. The right column box can be automatically filled with a grid using the `overlay` option and the default nodes.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable, xparse}

\tcbset{
    mybox/.style={
    breakable,
    frame hidden,
    opacityback=0,
    sharp corners,
    before skip=10pt,
    enhanced,
    left=6pt,
    right=0pt,
    bottom=0pt,
    boxsep=0pt,
    rightrule=0pt,
    pad at break*=0mm,
    borderline west={1.5pt}{0pt}{red},
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    coltitle=blue,
    title={\thetcbcounter. #1}
    }
}

\newtcolorbox[auto counter]{mybox}[2][]{%
    mybox=#2, #1
   }

\newtcolorbox[use counter from=mybox]{mygridbox}[2][]{
    mybox=#2, #1, 
    overlay ={
        \draw[green, thin, step=.5] (interior.north west) grid (interior.south east);
    },
}

\usepackage{mwe}
\begin{document}
Some text in one column \blindtext
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{mybox}[equal height group=A]{My title}
Some text in two columns \blindtext
\end{mybox}
\vfill\null
\columnbreak
\begin{mygridbox}[equal height group=A]{My second title}
\end{mygridbox}
\end{multicols}
\newpage
Some other text in one column
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{mybox}[equal height group=B]{My third title}
Some other text in two columns \blindtext[2]
\end{mybox}
\vfill\null
\columnbreak
\begin{mygridbox}[equal height group=B]{My fourth title}
\end{mygridbox}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Update: `tcbraster` version**

Instead of two independent boxes with `equal hight group` option, this structure can be easily made with a two columns `tcbitemize`. Following code shows a possible construction. An external counter is used and previous `tcolorboxes` are converted into `tcbset` styles to be applied to each `tcbitem`.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{geometry}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable, xparse}

\tcbset{
    mybox/.style={
    frame hidden,
    opacityback=0,
    sharp corners,
    before skip=10pt,
    enhanced,
    left=6pt,
    right=0pt,
    bottom=0pt,
    boxsep=0pt,
    rightrule=0pt,
    pad at break*=0mm,
    borderline west={1.5pt}{0pt}{red},
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    coltitle=blue,
    step=myboxcounter,
    title={\themyboxcounter. #1}
    },
    mygridbox/.style={
        mybox=#1,
        overlay ={%
        \draw[green, thin, step=.5] (interior.north west) grid (interior.south east);}
    }
}

\newcounter{myboxcounter}

\usepackage{mwe}
\begin{document}
Some text in one column \blindtext

\begin{tcbitemize}[raster columns=2, raster equal height, 
]
\tcbitem[mybox=My title]
Some text in two columns \blindtext
\tcbitem[mygridbox=My second title]
\end{tcbitemize}

\newpage
Some other text in one column
\begin{tcbitemize}[raster columns=2, raster equal height=rows, 
]
\tcbitem[mybox=My third title]
Some other text in two columns \blindtext[2]
\tcbitem[mygridbox=My fourth title]
\end{tcbitemize}
\end{document}
```